# Can't create D3D11 SwapChain in DLL

Tags: c++, hook, directx-11, direct3d

I'm currently trying to create an application which stops rendering of a game and takes screenshots of a Dx11 game every few seconds.
My approach for this is to create a basic SwapChain and then search the memory for something that has the same vTable as that one.

Now my problem is I'm completely stuck on the SwapChain creation. It results in an `DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL` every time and I can't figure out what parameter is wrong.

This is my code. I use VS2017 with x86 settings and nothing additional.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <d3d11.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")


bool CreateSwapChain() {

    // Gets handle of game
    HWND window = FindWindow(NULL, L"WARFRAME");
    if (window == NULL) return false;

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swap_desc;
    memset(&swap_desc, 0, sizeof(struct DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));
    swap_desc.BufferDesc.Width = NULL;  // Output window width
    swap_desc.BufferDesc.Height = NULL; // Output window height
    swap_desc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;  // No idea what the right value is here
    swap_desc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;   // No specific scanline method
    swap_desc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;   // Seems to be the best option
    swap_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;     // Multisampling count (default)
    swap_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;   // Multisampling quality (default
    swap_desc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_READ_ONLY;   // Dont need anything to do with the window
    swap_desc.BufferCount = 1;                      // Only one (the window)
    swap_desc.OutputWindow = window;    // Output window
    swap_desc.Windowed = TRUE;          // Game is windowed
    swap_desc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;    // Discard backbuffer after Present call
    swap_desc.Flags = NULL;

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL feature_level[1];
    feature_level[0] = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;

    IDXGISwapChain** swapchain_result = nullptr;

    HRESULT swapchain = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
        NULL,                       // Adapter. NULL because default adapter
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,   // Driver. Hardware because it provides the best performance
        NULL,                       // Software. NULL because driver is not software
        NULL,                       // Flags. No Flags because none are needed
        feature_level,              // Feature level. Features supported by Direct3D 11.0
        1,                          // Number of feature levels
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,          // SDK Version. Default
        &swap_desc,                 // Swapchain description defined above
        swapchain_result,           // Swapchain output
        NULL,                       // Return feature level
        NULL,                       // Discard feature level result
        NULL                        // Discard device context result
    );

    std::cout << "Swapchain result: " << std::hex << swapchain << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Swapchain pointer: " << std::hex << swapchain_result << std::endl;

    return true;
}


FILE* pCout;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fwdReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {

    if (fwdReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        AllocConsole();
        freopen_s(&pCout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        std::cout << "DLL attached" << std::endl;

        // Create swapchain
        std::cout << "Swapchain function result: " << CreateSwapChain() << std::endl;
    }

    else if (fwdReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH) {

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does that window handle returned by FindWindow belong to your thread?

Comment: add D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG to Flags. This way, D3D11 prints useful description of the error to the output window.

Comment: Asesh I'd assume so since im injecting, altough im not sure.
@geza sadly it doesn't really print anything

Comment: Try creating a new window to use instead of the existing (especially if you just want to grab the vtable of the result), also shouldn't usage be render target output? In C# but you can see similar here: https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook/blob/master/Capture/Hook/DXGI.cs and https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook/blob/master/Capture/Hook/DXHookD3D11.cs

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi#dxgi-responses-from-dllmain

> Because a DllMain function can't guarantee the order in which it loads and unloads DLLs, we recommend that your app's DllMain function not call Direct3D or DXGI functions or methods, including functions or methods that create or release objects.

Running function CreateSwapChain in a new thread may solve the problem.